# Validar la extensión de un correo electrónico con jQuery

Tags: jquery

Estoy realizando un sistema de registro para un aplicativo web. Me piden que solicite un correo personal y uno institucional. Quiero que al ingresar  el correo institucional (que son 2 posibles), valide si las extensiones ("@ejemplo", "@ejemplo2") son válidas con respecto a los correos institucionales.

En realidad, no sé cómo realizarlo. No soy muy experto con jQuery. He visto otras soluciones y sólo validan que el correo contenga todo lo necesario para ser un correo electrónico.

Agradecería mucho que me ayudaran.

Comment: Puedes compartir tu input en html para tener una idea de como lo tienes

Comment: Ya las respuestas me ayudaron. Muchas gracias. He calificado la que más me sirvió, con modificaciones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No necesitas **JQuery** para hacerlo simplemente podrías usar [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp):

```js
function validateEmail(email) {
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@((ejemplo|ejemplo2)+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return regex.test(email);
}

console.log(validateEmail('foo@ejemplo.com'))
console.log(validateEmail('foo@ejemplo2.com'))
console.log(validateEmail('foo@ejemplo3.com'))
```

Comment: Disculpa. Soy yo, otra vez. Es que tengo un problema: Me valida la extensión del correo, pero aún así me lo marca como inválido porque termina en .edu.co y noté que me lo valida si sólo es .com, entonces... ¿Cómo podría aumentar el valor de caracteres permitidos? He modificado el {2,4} a un {2,8}, pero no me funciona.

Comment: Quieres para la extensión específica ".edu.co" o cualquiera en ese formato ".xyz.ab"?

Comment: De preferencia, que sea con esa extensión. Sería mucho mejor.

Comment: var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@((ejemplo|ejemplo2)+\.+(edu.co))$/;

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, amigo.

Answer (score 2):

No es necesario usar **Jquery** para validar el correo con esta función es suficiente.

```
function isEmail(email) {
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return regex.test(email);
}
```